# 2 warnings: Cannot use a scalar value as an array and Illegal offset type in isset or empty

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

Here is the code that I wrote:

```
class init{
 private $time_spent;
 public function __construct(){
  $this->time_spent = array(); //<- caching variable
 }
 function get_course_unit_time_spent( $user_id,$course_id,$unit_id ){

    if(empty($this->time_spent) || empty($this->time_spent[$course_id]) || empty($this->time_spent[$course_id][$unit_id])){

        $this->time_spent[$course_id][$unit_id] = get_user_meta($user_id,'time_spent_'.$course_id.'_'.$unit_id,true);
        if( empty($this->time_spent[$course_id][$unit_id]) ){
            $this->time_spent[$course_id][$unit_id] = 0;
        }
    }

    return $this->time_spent[$course_id][$unit_id];

 }

 function get_course_time_spent( $user_id,$course_id ){

    if( empty($this->time_spent[$course_id]) ){
        if(!bp_course_is_member($course_id,$user_id))
            return 0;

        $time_spent = 0;
        $this->time_spent[$course_id] = array();
        $course_curriculum = bp_course_get_curriculum( $course_id );
        foreach ($course_curriculum as $key => $unit_id) {
            if( is_numeric($unit_id) ){
                $time_spent += $this->get_course_unit_time_spent( $user_id,$course_id,$unit_id );
            }
        }
        $this->time_spent[$course_id] = $time_spent;
    }

    return $this->time_spent[$course_id];

 }
}
```

There are lots of code but the issue is with the first function I wrote above, in two different places I am getting the above to warnings.

1) Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array on line 10 and 12 (in the above code).

2) Warning: Illegal offset type in isset or empty on line 8 (in the above code).

3) Warning: Illegal offset type on line 10, 11 and 12 (in the above code).

The second function is not throwing any error but whenever I use the 1st function or the second everytime the warning comes from the 1st function. I am not sure what is it, can someone help to correct it ?

UPDATE: Updated the code and now the first warning is gone but still getting the illegal ofset error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your calling `get_course_time_spent()`, which creates an array for
   `$this->time_spent[$course_id][$unit_id]` in
   `get_course_unit_time_spent()`
2. Then your setting `$this->time_spent[$course_id]` as an int once the foreach loop has finished.
3. Then on the next call to `get_course_unit_time_spent` your checking
   as if its an array `empty($this->time_spent[$course_id][$unit_id])`

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot

Comment: It fixed the first warning, but I am still getting the other warnings with illegal offset type.

Comment: Can you highlight in your code above where the errors are occurring, also update it with the code your now using.

Comment: The illegal ofset type warning is same as before on the same line

Comment: Can you tell me whats different from your code to: https://3v4l.org/Ppcif as im not having issues.

Comment: Your need to debug whats entering `get_course_unit_time_spent( $user_id,$course_id,$unit_id )`.

Comment: I saw your code, that's how it should work but on my localhost (XAMPP) not working.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I looked into the code from the scratch and the values which were coming from a different place, found a silly mistake there...